# Get difference of seconds beetween two dateTime

Tags: java, localdate

How can I calculate the difference in seconds between two dates?

I have this:

```
LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now(); // current date and time
LocalDateTime midnight = now.toLocalDate().atStartOfDay().plusDays(1); //midnight
```

In this case the time is: `now 2017-09-14T09:49:25.316 midnight 2017-09-15T00:00`

How i calculate `int second = ...?`

And the result, in this case, that i want return is 51035

How i can do?

> UPGRADE SOLVED

I try this:

```
DateTime now = DateTime.now();
DateTime midnight = now.withTimeAtStartOfDay().plusDays(1);
Seconds seconds = Seconds.secondsBetween(now, midnight);
int diff = seconds.getSeconds();
```

Now return the difference beetween the date in seconds in integer variable.

Thank all user for response.

Comment: Is this java sorry

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
int seconds = (int) ChronoUnit.SECONDS.between(now, midnight);
```

Comment: Clean solution. Actually cleaner then mine. Please notice Java 8 is needed to use the ChronoUnit class

Comment: @MathiasGhys `LocalDateTime` is already part of Java 8.

Comment: `between()` returns a `long`. If you want to assign to an `int` (which in this case is reasonable), I recommend a bounds check before casting.

Answer (score 0):

Convert them to seconds since Epoch and compare differences.

```
LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
LocalDateTime tomorrowMidnight = now.toLocalDate().atStartOfDay().plusDays(1);

ZoneId zone = ZoneId.systemDefault();
long nowInSeconds = now.atZone(zone).toEpochSecond();
long tomorrowMidnightInSeconds = tomorrowMidnight.atZone(zone).toEpochSecond();
System.out.println(tomorrowMidnightInSeconds - nowInSeconds);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do this through epochTime:

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.systemDefault();

LocalDateTime now = ...;
long epochInSecondsNow = now.atZone(zoneId).toEpochSecond();

LocalDateTime midnight = ...;
long epochInSecondsMidnight = midnight.atZone(zoneId).toEpochSecond();
```

and then calculate the difference:

```
long result = (epochInSecondsMidnight - epochInSecondsNow)
```